# Applying google script to all sheets except specific

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google script trying to resolve key issues in business flow.
Through search have come up with the below script for multi-level data validation for sheet **Template**.

How can I edit this script to run for all Sheets except specific ones (ex. Sheet1, Sheet 2)

I have found the option of excluding sheets with the code below, but not sure how to use it and where to input it

```
var excludes = [];
  // if (excludes.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1) return;
```

Thanks you in advance

```
var mainwsMaster = "Template";
var MenuWSname = "Master Menu"
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainwsMaster);
var wsMenu = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(MenuWSname);
var Menu = wsMenu.getRange(2,1,wsMenu.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
var firstColumn = 8;
var secondColumn = 9;
var thirdColumn = 10;

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainwsMaster && c === firstColumn && r > 6){ 
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r)
  } else if(wsName === mainwsMaster && c === secondColumn && r > 6){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  }
}//end onEdit


function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r,secondColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearDataValidations();
    }  else {
      ws.getRange(r,secondColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearDataValidations();
      var filteredOptions = Menu.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val });
      var filteredpiata = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1] } );
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(filteredpiata,cell);
    }
}


function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearDataValidations();
    }  else {
      ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = Menu.filter(function(o){return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
      var filteredpiata = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[2] } );
      var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(filteredpiata,cell);
    }
}


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned this code:

```
var excludes = [];
  // if (excludes.indexOf(s.getName()) != -1) return;
```

for your code it would look like this instead:

```
var excludes = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","OtherSheetToExclude","ETC"];
if (excludes.indexOf(wsName) != -1) {return};
```

You would place those two lines just after the wsName variable is declared in your onEdit(e) script.

It's basically saying. "Take the name of the sheet you've just edited and look for it in this list i just made called "Excludes".  If you find it in there, STOP running this function."

[image]

Comment: To be clear (and for the other scripters reading this), there is a better, more efficient way of adding the condition you're asking about.  

However, in my opinion, for a novice and for other future viewers of this answer, the simplicity of the way I tried to demonstrate outweighs the efficiency gains you would achieve by integrating the condition into the others that the function already has.

Comment: thank you very much, I will give it a go. What should I do with the initial definitions where all the vars are set and it is specific to the "Template" sheet? @MattKing

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var excludes = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
```

and then, change as following

```
if( excludes.indexOf(wsName) == -1 && c === firstColumn && r > 6)
```

for instance, focused on the onEdit function

```
var firstColumn = 8;
var secondColumn = 9;
var excludes = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(excludes.indexOf(wsName) == -1 && c === firstColumn && r > 6){ 
    activeCell.getSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('cas1')
  } else if(excludes.indexOf(wsName) == -1 && c === secondColumn && r > 6){
    activeCell.getSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('cas2')
  }
}//end onEdit
```

Comment: thanks a lot. am trying but getting nowhere. I think the problem is I have opened the script with
`var mainwsMaster = "Template";
var MenuWSname = "Master Menu"`
how should I treat this part? @Mike Steelson.. thank you

Comment: I have added an example focused on onEdit function that works fine. Your problem comes from the `applyFirstLevelValidation` and `applySecondLevelValidation` functions. As far as I don't understand what you are trying to do, I can't answer, but you use ws that is fixed on "Template". I suggest that you delete the line `var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainwsMaster);` and create `var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` at the beginning and inside these two functions

Comment: the script is supposed to apply multi-level validation to every sheets except specific ones.
I have a master Sheet ("Master Menu") with all the data in 3 columns (Ma,Mb,Mc,). In every other sheet I have 3 columns (A,B,C). I want the script to filter the validation choices for B5 depending on value in A5 and for C5 depending on B5. 
the function is working for one sheet but cannot figure applying to every sheet except helper ones...

Comment: ok, I understand. It will be very helpfull that you give us a link to a simplified spreadsheet.